# React Native Bug in animated Flatlist

Tags: react-native

I have different list of items displayed in horizontal FlatList.
So basically I have differents lists :

- List A
- List B
- List C
  ...

They are all horizontal and they share the same logic.

I'm using Animated to animate the flatlist with interpolation based on the index of the item.

It's working fine with some some lists displayed but not with others, like the index would be different from one list to another but I don't understand what's going on because all the lists  should start at  index [0]

Here you can see a screenshot to understand :
[FlatList bug display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BdI28.jpg)

As you can see the first list appears correctly on screen and is interpolated as 1.3x the normal size but the second which share the exact same logic is not interpolated.

Three main components :

- The section List that allows to display many lists : "BlockHomeChanelList"
- The main component that handle logic for animation with flatlList : "Block Home Channel List"
- The render Component "Block Video"

**Edited (Added this block)**
BlockHomeChanelList:

```
export default function BlockHomeChannelList({ showModal = false, startSlice = 0, endSlice = 1 }) {
  const categories = useSelector(getCategoriesList);

  return (
    <SectionList
      contentContainerStyle={{ marginLeft: MixinsStyles.wp(0) }}
      scrollEnabled={false}
      sections={categories.slice(startSlice, endSlice)}
      keyExtractor={(item) => item.id + item.name}
      renderItem={({ item, section: { name } }) => (
        <BlockHomeChannelItem
          showPlus={true}
          showModal={showModal}
          categoryItem={item}
          name={name}
        />
      )}
    />
  );
}
```

In that example, only one category is displayed (by using slide) and inside that categorie there are four lists.
Like one categorie (sports): and subcategories displayed in horizontal flatlist (basket, foot, hockey...)

Block Home Channel List :

```
export default function BlockHomeChannelItem({
  categoryItem,
  titleButton = "Voir toutes les vidéos",
  name,
  // showPlus = false,
}) {
  const navigation = useNavigation();
  const token = useSelector((state) => state.user.tokens.token);
  const [loading, setLoading] = React.useState(false);
  const [playlist, setPlaylist] = React.useState({});

  // Flatlist
  const CARD_WIDTH = MixinsStyles.wp(196);
  const AnimatedFlatList = Animated.createAnimatedComponent(FlatList);
  const animated = useRef(new Animated.Value(0)).current;
  const padding = (width - CARD_WIDTH) / 2;
  const marginRight = MixinsStyles.wp(18);
  const flatListRef = useRef(null);


  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (token && categoryItem.id && !playlist?.id) {
      getChannelPlaylist(token, categoryItem.id).then((data) => {
        setPlaylist(data);
        setLoading(false);
      });
    }
  }, [token, categoryItem.id, playlist?.id]);

  if (loading || !playlist?.videos?.length || !playlist?.activeVideoCount) {
    return null;
  }
  return (
    <View style={{ marginBottom: MixinsStyles.hp(35) }}>

     *...TextTitleCode*

      <AnimatedFlatList
        data={playlist?.videos}
        horizontal
        ref={flatListRef}
        showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
        keyExtractor={(item) => item}
        onScroll={Animated.event(
          [
            {
              nativeEvent: {
                contentOffset: {
                  x: animated,
                },
              },
            },
          ],
          { useNativeDriver: true }
        )}
        scrollEventThrottle={16}
        getItemLayout={(data, index) => ({
          length: CARD_WIDTH + marginRight,
          offset: (CARD_WIDTH + marginRight) * index,
          index,
        })}
        snapToInterval={CARD_WIDTH + marginRight}
        contentContainerStyle={{ paddingHorizontal: padding, height: MixinsStyles.hp(200) }}
        renderItem={({ item, index }) => {
          const inputRange = [
            (index - 1) * (CARD_WIDTH + marginRight), //
            index * (CARD_WIDTH + marginRight),
            (index + 1) * (CARD_WIDTH + marginRight),
          ];
          const scale = animated.interpolate({
            inputRange,
            outputRange: [1, 1.28, 1],
            extrapolate: "clamp",
          });
          const opacity = animated.interpolate({
            inputRange,
            outputRange: [0.5, 1, 0.5],
            extrapolate: "clamp",
          });
          const myScale = { transform: [{ scale }] };
          return (
            <BlockVideo
              showModal={showModal}
              item={item}
              resume={resume}
              favorite={favorite}
              animatedStyle={{ opacity, myScale }}
            />
          );
        }}
      />
     *....buttonCode*
    </View>
  );
}
```

BlockVideo :

```
export default function BlockVideo({
  item,
  resume,
  favorite,
  animatedStyle,
}) {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const navigation = useNavigation();

  const video = useSelector((state) =>
    state.videos.filter((element) => !!element.active).find((element) => element["@id"] === item)
  );

  if (!video?.id) {
    return null;
  }

  return (
       <Animated.View
      style={[
        animatedStyle.myScale,
        {
          opacity: animatedStyle.opacity,
          alignSelf: "center",
          marginRight: MixinsStyles.wp(36),
        },
      ]}
    >
      <TouchableOpacity
        onPress={...code}
      >
        <ImageBackground
          borderRadius={5}
          style={[
            styles.containerImageBackground,
            { width: search ? "100%" : MixinsStyles.hp(196) },
          ]}
          source={
            video?.picture?.contentUrl
              ? { uri: video?.picture?.contentUrl }
              : AssetsImg.EXPERT_PICTURE
          }
        >
          <GradientImageBackground variant="black" style={styles.gradientImage}>
            {favorite && (
              <AntDesign style={styles.iconFavorite} name="star" size={13} color="#FF0000" />
            )}
            <View style={styles.textPosition}>
              <SharedText textAlign="center" size="12" family="bold">
                {video?.name}
              </SharedText>
              {resume && <ProgressVideoBlock width={50} />}
            </View>
          </GradientImageBackground>
        </ImageBackground>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </Animated.View>
  );
}

Stylesheet: {...some code}
```

If I change the input range like that, it reverse the working items  :

```
 const inputRange = [
            (index - 2) * (CARD_WIDTH + marginRight), //
            (index -1) * (CARD_WIDTH + marginRight),
            (index) * (CARD_WIDTH + marginRight),
          ];
```

So the question is how can I have items displayed properly for all my lists ?
What's going wrong with my code ?

thanks a lot

Comment: I just see one instance of `Animated.FlatList` in your code though. Do post the instance of another one too? Which one is not working?

Comment: You are right I'm using SectionList to display many list but didn't add it in first instance to make it clearer. I just edited my original post. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I found out what's going wrong in my code.
The logic behind flatlist is good.

The issue is on the last component "BlockVideo", here :

```
 const video = useSelector((state) =>
    state.videos.filter((element) => !!element.active).find((element) => element["@id"] === item)
  );

  if (!video?.id) {
    return null;
  }
```

As it filters element by id and not displaying items that don't have id, the index of element is still the same but nothing is displayed on the screen which creates a gap